# Why is this MYSQL not in query so slow?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that checks against another table to see if an email is in there and matches other conditions. However it takes extremely long with only 10k rows. Everything is indexed properly. I was under the assumption that the NOT IN sub-query would only run once? Is there a better way to write this?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(end_users.email)
        FROM
            `end_users`
        WHERE
            `email` NOT IN (
                SELECT
                    email
                FROM
                    email_que
                WHERE
                    email_cronjob_id IN (1, 2)
            )
    ) count_results
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `email` in the `end_users` table?

Comment: yes, email is indexed on both tables

Comment: Well, let's see the query plan so we can tell what's happening...

Comment: One nesting can be removed using `COUNT(DISTINCT end_users.email)`

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the sql avoiding `NOT IN`

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS numrows
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(eu.email)
        FROM
            end_users eu
        WHERE
         NOT   EXISTS   (
                SELECT
                    email
                FROM
                    email_que eq
                WHERE
                    eq.email_cronjob_id IN (1,2)  AND eu.email  =  eq.email
            )
    ) count_results
```

Comment: The same comment as to the other answer: the optimiser should be able to build the same plan from either query.

Comment: What if it's not @zerkms?

Comment: @cdaiga then it's not obvious why this query should be any better than the OPs query (given that every query is transformed to a correlated subquery in mysql anyway)

Comment: He can test and see the execution time.

Comment: @cdaiga that's not how you performance optimise the queries. But anyway, I have nothing to add: I think the answer about performance optimisations should come with some explanation about why it (at least theoretically) is better. At this point I fail to see how this very answer is supposed to improve anything. If anybody provides links to a reference or execution plan that confirms it, it would be helpful, otherwise it's totally not a scientific way to performance optimise.